# haskell write large string

Tags: haskell

Hello Stackoverflow Community.

I'm relativly new to Haskell and i have noticed writing large strings to a file with
`writeFile` or `hPutStr` is extremly slow.

For a 1.5 Mb String my Programm (compiled with ghc) takes about 2 seconds while the
"same" code in c++ only takes about 0.1 seconds.
The string is generated from a list with about 10000 elements and then dumped with `writeFile`. I have also tried to traverse the the list with `mapM_` and `hPutStr` with the same result.

Is there a faster way to write a large string?

**Update**

As @applicative pointed out the following code finishes with a 2MB file in no time

```
main = readFile "input.txt" >>= writeFile "ouput.txt"
```

So my problem seems to be somewhere else. Here are my two implementations for
Writing the list (WordIndex and CoordList are typealiases for a Map and a List)

with hPutStrLn

```
-- Print to File
indexToFile :: String -> WordIndex -> IO ()
indexToFile filename index =
    let 
        indexList = map (\(k, v) -> entryToString k v)  (Map.toList index)
    in do
        output <- openFile filename WriteMode
        mapM_ (\v -> hPutStrLn output v) indexList
        hClose output


-- Convert Listelement to String
entryToString :: String -> CoordList -> String
entryToString key value = (embedString 25 key) ++ (coordListToString value) ++ "\n"
```

with writeFile

```
-- Print to File
indexToFile :: String -> WordIndex -> IO ()
indexToFile filename index = writeFile filename (indexToString "" index)

-- Index to String
indexToString :: String -> WordIndex -> String
indexToString lead index = Map.foldrWithKey (\k v r -> lead ++ (entryToString k v) ++ r) "" index
```

Maybe you guys can help me a little in finding a speed up here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What sort of contents has the string? `ByteString` writes are as fast as it gets, so if you can do a cheap conversion to a `ByteString`, that would be an option.

Comment: I don't believe that writing files has anything to do with it; `main = readFile "1.5mb.txt" >>= writeFile "1.5mb2.txt"` takes `0m0.089s` here, not 2 seconds and is thus faster than what you report for C++. At about 50 MB it begins to approach 2 sec; similarly `writeFile "big.txt" (show [1..250000])` takes 0.06 sec and makes a 1.6 mb file.

Comment: You're right @applicative my problem seems to be somewhere else. I'll post some code

Comment: Please provide enough code that we can compile, run, and observe a two-second pause.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could, for instance, use the `Text` type from the module `Data.Text` or `Data.Text.Lazy`, which internally represent text in a more efficient way (namely UTF-16) than lists of Chars do.

When writing binary data (which may or may not contain text encoded in some form) you can use `ByteString`s or their lazy equivalents.

When modifying `Text` or `ByteStrings`, some operations to modify them are faster on the lazy versions. If you only want to read from such a string after creating it the non-lazy versions can generally be recommended.

Answer (score 2):

This is well-known problem. The default Haskell `String` type is simple `[Char]` and is slow by definition and is dead slow if it is constructed lazily (usual situation). However, as list, it allows simple and clean processing using list combinators and is useful when performance is not an issue. If it is, one should use `ByteString` or `Text` packages. `ByteString` is better as it is shipped with ghc, but does not provide unicode support. `ByteString`-based utf8 packages are available on hackage.